# Mic is being used by some other application ( Which ? )

Tags: samsung, microphone

I have a Samsung mobile ( S9 Plus ), When I use an app called "BixBy", sometimes it does not work and message is that mic is used being used by some other application and hence "Bixby" can not function.

In such cases, how may I know that which application is using mic at present?

Comment: Please check this, tap on recents/overview button to show background running apps, may be apps like camera, voice recorder, phone is running. Or else check that bixby is your default assist and voice input from settings.

Answer (score 0):

Install the app named Unhack from playstore or from the link given below. It gives you a list of all applications using mic, camera etc. separately.
https://www.apkmonk.com/app/com.lucideustech.unhack/